# PHP won't connect to SQL Server

Tags: php, apache, sql-server-2005

I am running Windows 7 (32 bit) and have installed Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.1 thread safe.  I installed these seperately as I previously tried a WAMP bundle and did not like it as I found it problematic.  The apache and PHP components run fine.  I have the apache port set to 7777 and when I go to the URL http://localhost:7777/phpinfo.php the PHP Info appears.  Also I can create a basic PHP Hello World and it can be viewed in the browser.  I need to connect to a SQL Server 2005 instance to learn PHP on a project.  I have downloaded the SQLSRV30.EXE and extracted the files and placed the DLL's php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll in the folder C:\PHP\ext then placed the following entries in the php.ini file

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

Restarted Apache and in the phpinfo list it does not state any SQL Server attributes.  And when I try to run the example below the browser states - Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().  I have found several examples on stackoverflow but they concern using wamp.  What am I doing wrong here please?

Update: I actually installed NetBeans for PHP and created a new project with the same code below in the index.php page and when I run it the error is the same

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check SQL Server Connection</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <?php
    $serverName = "IT90334\SQLEXPRESS";
    $connectionInfo = array('Database' => 'AdventureWorks');
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if ($conn) {
       echo "Connection Established.<br />";
    } else {
       echo "Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL.<br />";
       die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the path to the php.ini file listed by `phpinfo()` match up with the ini file you changed?

Comment: Are there any startup errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: @MattGibson Yes.  I checked the listed file is in C:\PHP\php.ini and thats the one I changed

Comment: @danjam when I un-comment the parameter error_log = php_errors.log in the php.ini the apache web server fails to restart

Comment: @MattGibson I have this progressed and the connection established showing in the browser but now trying to retrieve some data and netbeans does not like the "sqlsrv_query" and states it is a misspelled word.  Heres my code $query = "SELECT Name FROM Production.Location"
        
        // Execute the query and return the records
        $result = sqlsrv_query($query)

Comment: @danjam I have this progressed and the connection established showing in the browser but now trying to retrieve some data and netbeans does not like the "sqlsrv_query" and states it is a misspelled word.  Heres my code $query = "SELECT Name FROM Production.Location"
        
        // Execute the query and return the records
        $result = sqlsrv_query($query)

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether Netbeans likes it or not (presumably this is just some editor's syntax-checking which might not work with non-core extension DLLs?) It only matters if the PHP interpreter likes it. Does it actually work? If not, what are the symptoms, and what's your new code that's showing them up?

Comment: @MattGibson I have that misspelled dealt with but now while trying to get a row count it doesn't appear to like it and outputs nothing from the following code $rowcount = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);
if ($rowCount === false){
   echo "failure";
}
else {
   echo $rowCount;
}

Answer (score 0):

Found something on another forum that hinted that the Microsoft driver SQLSRV30.exe was too knew for my PHP set up.  I am running Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3.1 and so found that SQLSVR20.exe driver was also compatible with PHP 5.3.1 so download SQLSVR20 and replaced the files php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll with php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll and php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc6.dll (MY PHP setup was around vc6 too) then amended the php.ini parameters.  Upon restarting Apache this got the process further but said I required SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client which I located and installed and then the SQLSVR was listed in the PHPInfo url and the connection worked